# Can "Is it possible for a planet to become moon of a gas giant and sustain life as is?" be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, too-broad, reopening-questions

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/83311/39269) was put on hold stating too broad. I have further edited the question to limit the ​scope of answers. Please consider reopening it again.

Answer (score 5):

After you made this meta post, the question was reopened and then closed as a duplicate.

Duplicates aren't bad!  If you didn't find the linked questions, perhaps other people won't either.  And perhaps your question will help them find them.  Meanwhile, the other questions have answers already, so with luck that helps you.

If you don't agree that your question is a duplicate, then you should edit the question to clarify how it is different, and then the community might reopen it again.

Thanks for bringing your question to meta and working with the community to build a collection of good questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard common thing to do and so there's a button for that.  It might even be automatic upon editing — I'm not sure when that is triggered.  Look at the grey link worde just under the tags.  It's in the review queue as I write this.

Comment: There seem to be mutliple criteria for putting a question automatically into the reopen queue. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/352819) is the Meta post that seems to be the most useful, though it's quite old. Basically if the author edits the question within 5 days or someone else edits it and the author hasn't flagged it himself or if it's especially popular it will automatically be added.